# Cauchy Goursat theorem puzzle

Tags: complex-analysis

I am a bit confused...
What is the value of  integral of an analytic function  in an annular domain  along a closed contour ??
is it necessarily zero or not ?
 My intuitions  say  it will be zero by Cauchy Gaursat theorem

Thnx and regards

Comment: Try with $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$. Note that $\displaystyle\int_{|z|=1} - \int_{|z|=2} f(z)dz$ is a an integral along a closed contour and it is $0$ whenever $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $1 \le |z| \le 2$

Comment: Also, proving the Cauchy integral theorem for analytic functions is easy : look at the case $f(z) = z^n$ that we know a primitive of. What is much harder is the Cauchy integral theorem for holomorphic functions.

Comment: Do you mean if the function is analytic *only* on an annular domain? If so, then I suppose the answer depends on whether or not such functions exist and are necessarily so (that is, they can't be analytically continued so as to fill the interior region). If such functions do exist, then C-G would not apply since it requires the function to be analytic on the enclosure of the contour.

Comment: @WB-man why we cannot apply CG as it only require analyticity of the function inside the contour  I am saying that function is defined only in the annular domain and it is analytic there

Comment: Because the statement of CG requires the function to be defined EVERYWHERE within the enclosure of the contour. If the function is undefined at any point inside (e.g. $1/z$) then the hypotheses of CG won't be met and hence CG is inconclusive. The only possible exception to this if the function can be analytically continued so as to "fill" the undefined region and hence satisfy the CG hypotheses (i.e. if the undefined region is *removable*).

Comment: Brilliant  argument @WB-man  I will work on it